# Export all localizations on the command line in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, xcodebuild

I have 26 languages successfully localized and tested. I am able to successfully export all 26 localizations with option: "Editor" -> "Export for Localization...", then selecting all of them.

However, when I use the following xcodebuild command, it exports my default language "en", and nothing else.

```
xcodebuild -exportLocalizations -localizationPath TempLocalizationExport
```

How do I export all twenty-six Localizations rather than just "en"?

There are no command line errors outputted from the command.

I've seached everywhere for official xcodebuild commandline command documentation on developer.apple.com, and I can't find a verbose and helpful source that addresses additional -exportLocalizations options and standard behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html):

> To export localizations, enter this command in Terminal, replacing the
>   *dirpath* and *projectname* arguments:
>
> ```
> xcodebuild -exportLocalizations -localizationPath <dirpath> -project <projectname> [[-exportLanguage <targetlanguage>]]
> ```
>
> The exported XLIFF files are placed in *dirpath*. Optionally, use the
>   exportLanguage argument to export other localizations.

**UPDATE:**

The OP discovered that multiple languages can be exported by repeating the -exportLanguage argument. For example, this command exports two languages:

```
xcodebuild -exportLocalizations -localizationPath TempLocalizationExport -exportLanguage es -exportLanguage ru
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems we're restricted to exporting one language at a time. Do you draw the same conclusion?

Comment: I don't have an app that uses localization so I was just going by the docs. Did you try sending a list of languages, perhaps in quotes or comma-delimited? The docs are vague!

Answer (score 0):

Seems xcodebuild doesn't support auto export all localizations at this time.

But we can do it through Xcode interface.

[image: Export menu in Xcode]

Also it's possible auto select all localizations with a script. Read `knownRegions` section in project.pbxproj, loop to argument format.

Comment: As the initial question describes the Editor -> "Export for Localizations" option already and asks for a scripted approach, the knownRegions is promising. Can you provide the xcodebuild command that does this to finish answering the question?